# Error on Fortigate SSL when connecting to CIFS file server

Tags: fortigate, sslvpn

I am having trouble connecting to a Windows file server via Fortigate SSL.

I enter the host name of my file server in Connection Tool section of my SSL portal and then a window asking for log in credentials pops up.

I enter them and click `Login` after what I get an error with `Invalid HTTP request`. This server is a domain member and uses AD DS for authentication so I enter credentials in this form: `fname.lname@domain.com`. But even if I leave them blank and click login, still... the same thing happens.

[image: Error]

I tried a different server that is not a domain member (linux server) and has anonymous login, I just left credentials blank and it connected just fine to the server.

- The UTM device is Fortigate 300D
- Firmware version is the newest one v5.2 (was the same with v5.0)

What could be wrong? Doesn't it work with servers that are domain members?

### Update

I was actually able to login by specifying an IP address instead of a DNS name when connecting. Also I had to use `DOMAIN\user` notation to login, otherwise it does not work. The DNS is reachable for sure as it works with the other server

Comment: This is still an issue on 5.2 even. Still have to append DOMAIN\ to the name to login. Will open ticket to see if they have a suggestion.

Comment: I recently had this start with on our portal. At first I thought it was caused by and update from 6.0.4 to 6.0.5.
I ended up doing a packet capture and found that in lieu of a domain\username Fortigate sends NT\username, which our file server is (now?) interpenetrating as an anonymous login.
I've pushed this up to Infrastructure, and seeing if the timing of when this stopped working is close to any patches or changes.
I have a ticket open, and I've asked support to supply some way to force a default SMB domain if a domain is not supplied in the username. The dns-suffix setting in SSL settings